# Wood splinters bursting

Tags: modifiers

How to create such wood splinters as in the screenshots below? I found videos and tutorials on how to break a wood model with the boolean modifier but it found to only break it in half and not like in the screenshots one side of the log kinda bursting out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you need it to be animated? This tutorial should help:

https://youtu.be/Y6nJFTTv8Tg?si=fL-Lfc6NCFams7yZ

This is for glass but it shows how you can control the cell fracture modifier to control the pattern of the fracturing/splintering. The base geometry is also important - if you want to a lot of long splintery pieces the plank should be subdivided into longish pieces to begin with.

Comment: @JamesSiewert It should be static thats why the cell fracture kinda gives me a headache :/

Comment: It's still probably the fastest way IMO.